# Can't start an application from the launcher, but can from dash and rightcliking

Tags: unity, launcher

After I started an application and stopped it I cannot launch that application again by clicking on the launcher icon. Nothing would happen.

I can however launch that application through the dash or, right clicking on the launcher icon and choosing "New Window" (Firefox for instance).

That problem seems to appear for all apps in the launcher, like system settings, nautilus, firefox.

Do you know how to fix that behavior?

Comment: Wait are you saying you need the launcher on every screen to fix this? if thats the case that sounds like a bug

Comment: I went into the settings and set it to show up on both monitors. That fixed the problem. This is a bug.

Comment: Bug in Unity, there's a release fixing the issue already https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1291362

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you got it set to only display on one monitor (assuming you have more than one)?

I had the same issue, as soon as I selected it to display on both monitors under Display Settings, it stopped happening.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, that's it! Anyone know if this bug is already filed?

Comment: Yeah, I'm having this exact issue. Please link me to a bug otherwise I'll create one tomorrow. EDIT: Can't see one: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bugs?field.tag=launcher

Comment: I submitted a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1310240